# pyautogui как настроить кликер с открытой вкладкой

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, автоматизация, pyautogui

могу ли я запустить скрипт на уже открытую вкладку в браузере?Чтобы он не открывал новую через browser.open_new(),а находил по урлу уже заранее мною открытую и работал с ней
Очень нуждаюсь в помощи

```
       import pyautogui as pag
       import webbrowser
       emails = ["name1","name2","name3"]
       for email in emails:
           webbrowser.open_new("crazycoolwebsite.com")
           pag.click(x=xcoord1, y=ycoord1)    
           pag.click(x=xcoord2, y=ycoord2)    
           pag.typewrite(email)               
           pag.press("enter")
           pag.hotkey('ctrl', 'w')
```